# Allow special characters in e-mail Regex

Tags: reactjs, regex, typescript, jsx

What is a proper Regex code to allow special characters like `. _ -` in email field

I have this Regex right now `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/,`

The above Regex only allow e-mails such as `joedow@gmail.com`

`joe.dow@gmail.com` does not work

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add those characters to the Regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/xKkKIQ/1

This will make the regex consider `.`, `_` and `-`. If you want any other characters, add them in the same way.